# Vectorize loss function with complex indexing

Tags: python, vectorization, pytorch

I have written a loss function in pytorch, however, it is too slow.
Thus, I'm trying to vectorize it.

## Description

Given two meshes, it computes the distortion between patches (i.e. set of vertices) defined on them. The distortion is how much the distances between each pair of points changes.

[image]

- Patches may have different sizes
- This assumes a correspondence between M and N.
- The loss accept batches.

## Non-vectorized code

```py
def loss_func(y_pred, batch):
    y_true = batch['vertices']
    patches: Tuple(Tensor,...) = batch['patches']

    loss = 0
    for i in range(y_pred.shape[0]):
        patch_loss = 0
        for patch in patches:
            dist_a = torch.pdist(y_pred[i][patch])
            dist_b = torch.pdist(y_true[i][patch])

            patch_loss += torch.sum((dist_a - dist_b) ** 2)

        loss += patch_loss
    return loss / y_pred.shape[0]
```

## Vectorization attempt

```py
def loss_func(y_pred, batch):
    y_true = batch['vertices']
    patches: Tuple(Tensor,...) = batch['patches']

    pred_dists = torch.cdist(y_pred, y_pred)
    true_dists = torch.cdist(y_true, y_true)

    diff_dists = (pred_dists - true_dists) ** 2

    loss = 0
    for patch in patches:
        d = diff_dists[:, patch, :][:, :, patch]
        loss += torch.sum(d, dim=(1, 2)) / 2

    return loss.mean()
```

## Problem

It is still too slow.
I'm encountering difficulties in the vectorization since the patches may have different dimensions, thus they can't be put in a tensor.

I have the feeling that I could use directly the adjacency matrix to vectorize the code, without gathering the vertex indices in patches.

The patches are computed in this way:

```py
def get_patch(vertex_index, vertex2vertex):
    return vertex2vertex[vertex_index, :].nonzero().squeeze(-1)
```

## Working example

I prepared a self contained example to test and experiment with the two functions, with some benchmarks.
In the benchmark there is the same loss function without patches (i.e. just the distortion between all the vertices) as reference time

```py
import torch
import time

device = 'cuda'
precision = torch.double
batch_size = 8
num_vertices = 400
dim = 2

y_pred = torch.rand(batch_size, num_vertices, dim, device=device, dtype=precision)
y_true = torch.rand(batch_size, num_vertices, dim, device=device, dtype=precision)

adjacency = (torch.rand(num_vertices, num_vertices, device=device, dtype=precision) > 0.95).to(precision)

def get_patch(vertex_index, vertex2vertex):
    return vertex2vertex[vertex_index, :].nonzero().squeeze(-1)

patches = tuple(get_patch(i, adjacency) for i in range(num_vertices))
batch = {
    'vertices': y_true,
    'patches': patches
}

def loss_func(y_pred, batch):
    y_true = batch['vertices']
    patches: Tuple(Tensor,...) = batch['patches']

    loss = 0
    for i in range(y_pred.shape[0]):
        patch_loss = 0
        for patch in patches:
            dist_a = torch.pdist(y_pred[i][patch])
            dist_b = torch.pdist(y_true[i][patch])

            patch_loss += torch.sum((dist_a - dist_b) ** 2)

        loss += patch_loss
    return loss / y_pred.shape[0]

def loss_func_vec(y_pred, batch):
    y_true = batch['vertices']
    patches: Tuple(Tensor,...) = batch['patches']

    pred_dists = torch.cdist(y_pred, y_pred)
    true_dists = torch.cdist(y_true, y_true)

    diff_dists = (pred_dists - true_dists) ** 2

    loss = 0
    for patch in patches:
        d = diff_dists[:, patch, :][:, :, patch]
        loss += torch.sum(d, dim=(1, 2)) / 2

    return loss.mean()

def reference_no_patches(y_pred, batch):
    y_true = batch['vertices']
    da = torch.cdist(y_pred, y_pred)
    db = torch.cdist(y_true, y_true)
    return torch.sum((da - db) ** 2) / y_true.shape[0] / 2

print(f'LOSS FUNCTION (ITERATION): TIME (LOSS)')
print()

for i in range(5):
    start_time = time.time()
    res = loss_func(y_pred, batch)
    torch.cuda.synchronize()
    print(f'Standard {i}:\t{time.time() - start_time:.4f}s ({res:.5f})')
print()

for i in range(5):
    start_time = time.time()
    res = loss_func_vec(y_pred, batch)
    torch.cuda.synchronize()
    print(f'Vectorized {i}:\t{time.time() - start_time:.4f}s ({res:.5f})')
print()

for i in range(5):
    start_time = time.time()
    res = reference_no_patches(y_pred, batch)
    torch.cuda.synchronize()
    print(f'Reference without patches {i}:\t{time.time() - start_time:.4f}s ({res:.5f})')
```

```
LOSS FUNCTION (ITERATION): TIME (LOSS)

Standard 0: 0.3311s (9744.87875)
Standard 1: 0.2853s (9744.87875)
Standard 2: 0.2929s (9744.87875)
Standard 3: 0.2972s (9744.87875)
Standard 4: 0.2714s (9744.87875)

Vectorized 0:   0.0254s (9744.87875)
Vectorized 1:   0.0251s (9744.87875)
Vectorized 2:   0.0262s (9744.87875)
Vectorized 3:   0.0242s (9744.87875)
Vectorized 4:   0.0241s (9744.87875)

Reference without patches 0:    0.0063s (9695.41083)
Reference without patches 1:    0.0062s (9695.41083)
Reference without patches 2:    0.0062s (9695.41083)
Reference without patches 3:    0.0066s (9695.41083)
Reference without patches 4:    0.0067s (9695.41083)
```

## Context

The matrices involved are small. The number of vertices in each mesh is ~500, thus the adjacency matrix is `[500, 500]`.
The patches may vary in dimension, however each one is << 500. There is one patch for each vertex (i.e. each vertex is the center of a patch), thus the number of patches is O(n!) (thus, I can't stack the patches into a single vector to perform the indexing).

I used the double precision in the example only to avoid numerical errors in the results, I plan to use float precision.

Finally, I will be happy to receive any suggestions on how to improve speed!

## Update

Due to this [bug](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/24345) I have to be careful with the memory allocation.
I rewrote the vectorized code as:

```
def loss_func_vec_mem(y_pred, batch):
    y_true = batch['vertices']
    patches: Tuple(Tensor,...) = batch['patches']

    loss = 0
    for patch in patches:
        pred = y_pred[:, patch, :]
        true = y_true[:, patch, :]

        pred_dists = torch.cdist(pred, pred)
        true_dists = torch.cdist(true, true)

        diff_dists = (pred_dists - true_dists) ** 2

        loss += torch.sum(diff_dists, dim=(1, 2)) 
    return loss.mean() / 2
```

Although it's even slower:

```
LOSS FUNCTION (ITERATION): TIME (LOSS)

Vec mem 0:  0.0484s (14685.45521)
Vec mem 1:  0.0489s (14685.45521)
Vec mem 2:  0.0471s (14685.45521)
Vec mem 3:  0.0471s (14685.45521)
Vec mem 4:  0.0459s (14685.45521)

Vectorized 0:   0.0271s (29370.91043)
Vectorized 1:   0.0262s (29370.91043)
Vectorized 2:   0.0320s (29370.91043)
Vectorized 3:   0.0266s (29370.91043)
Vectorized 4:   0.0263s (29370.91043)

Standard 0: 0.1680s (14685.45521)
Standard 1: 0.1614s (14685.45521)
Standard 2: 0.1639s (14685.45521)
Standard 3: 0.1606s (14685.45521)
Standard 4: 0.1694s (14685.45521)

Reference without patches 0:    0.0049s (12874.01275)
Reference without patches 1:    0.0105s (12874.01275)
Reference without patches 2:    0.0103s (12874.01275)
Reference without patches 3:    0.0092s (12874.01275)
Reference without patches 4:    0.0100s (12874.01275)
```

Comment: Why don't you pad your `patches` tuple?

Comment: In each patch there are the indices of the vertices contained in that patch, which value should I use to pad them? Once padded how would you use that matrix? I feel like there should be a way to use the adjacency matrix, that in a way contains all the patches information together